# Name resolution with cloudstack cloud manager

Tags: dns, cloud, fqdn

I have just set up a cloud using cloudstack 3.0. I have installed its management server on system having IP address 10.129.34.15, which can be accessed in browser using  following url:
        "http://10.129.34.15:8080/client"

Now I made an entry in DNS server as follows:
10.129.34.15:8080 maps to www.cse.iitb.ac.in/rcloud

So I can access the cloudstack interface in browser using:
http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/rcloud/client

Now when I use "http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/rcloud/client" and I enter my username and password in the interface, then it says invalid username/password and does not allow me to login. But if I use "http://10.129.34.15:8080/client" while I am in same subnet, then it allows me to login and everything is fine there.

Answer (score 1):

This may not help my karma, but here goes:

Due to CloudStack being a relatively new Apache Foundation Incubator project, the best place to ask this question is on the **cloudstack-users@incubator.apache.org** email list.

You can subscribe by sending an email to **cloudstack-users-subscribe@incubator.apache.org** [details here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-cloudstack-users/)

The bulk of the original development team still read the email list, so you'll get a response very quickly.