# Install Cloudstack 3.0 on Ubuntu 10.04 single node

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, citrix

Is it possible to install cloudstack 3.0 on single node using ubuntu 10.04 64 bit with virtualization support CPU ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two approaches, but first some background.

For readers unaccustomed to cloud OS, let me explain that you will need at least two machines:  one to run the CloudOS and another to be the compute node.  The CloudOS is a managment server that allocates compute resources, the compute node is a machine running a hypervisor that supplies the resources being allocated.

'Single node' can mean either one physical server running the whole cloud or a cloud managing a single physical server, depending on whether you count the management server as a node.

To run everything on a single machine, you can simulate the compute node using a hypervisor.  An example of this is [DevCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/DevCloud), which runs the whole Cloudstack using VirtualBox.  Provided you can get Virtualbox to run on Ubuntu 10.04, you are sorted.

If instead you want have two machines, and Ubuntu 10.04 is installed on the machine that you want to be the CloudStack management server, then you need to install the management server on Ubuntu.  The binaries for running on Ubuntu 10.04 are at the bottom of the [Latest Release page](http://incubator.apache.org/cloudstack/downloads.html).  There is a [video demonstrating the installation on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAHdEPiXq74)

However, a better solution to upgrade.  CloudStack 4.0 is built to run on Ubuntu 12.04.  Why not use this?

Comment: CloudStack 4.0 is an incubator , I think I'll try it. Thanks for your solution

Comment: Apache CloudStack is an incubator project, but Apache CloudStack 4.0 is an official release.

Comment: I got an error when using CloudStack 4.0 

BUILD FAILED
/home/meruvian/Cloudstack/incubator-cloudstack/build.xml:48: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/meruvian/Cloudstack/incubator-cloudstack/build/build-aws-api.xml:34: taskdef class org.apache.axis2.tool.ant.AntCodegenTask cannot be found

any solution ?

Comment: Sounds like you're not building using the mvn build script.  Post details of the command you are using to the cloudstack-dev mailing list.  To subscribe, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074315/name-resolution-with-cloudstack-cloud-manager/11395727#11395727 You'll need to change the mailing list from cloudstack-users to cloudstack-dev

Comment: I just noticed that you've posted 10 questions and accepted none of them.  I don't know if this is deliberate, but it is hardly in the spirit of the StackOverflow.

If you are getting help, then you should really be acknowledging this by accepting answers and upvoting responses.  If you're not getting help, then think about posting elsewhere.